# filtering out an array of items setting state

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am looking to filter through an array and return all elements of the array except the element which has been clicked on, so I have a map of list elements each with a `key={index}` of their map, `onClick` it should call my remove function, and pass in the index of the element to be removed, I then need to filter over that array, remove the element, update state, and send this information to my backend.

here is the delete function

```js
  const deleteItem = (id) => {
    // use filter, to loop through all pieces of index
    const element = list.todoItems.indexOf(id - 1);
    setList({ todoItems: list.todoItems.filter(element !== id) });
    console.log(list.todoItems);
    dispatch(updateTodo(list));
  };
```

here is the mapped array

```js
{list.todoItems.map((Item, index) => (
                <div
                  // setup anonymous function, that will call
                  // ONLY when the div
                  // is clicked on.
                  key={index}
                  onClick={() => deleteItem(index)}
                >
                  {/* list item, gets text from props */}
                  <li>{Item}</li>
                </div>
              ))}
```

I must be missing something, because this should work, Though i may have to shift gears and have each item as an actual object in my database, though id rather not do this as i feel an array of strings is more than appropriate for this app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to subtract one from the index on the indexOf function

And for this case, splice works better than filter

```
const deleteItem = (id) => {
  const element = list.todoItems.indexOf(id);
  setList({ todoItems: {...list}.todoItems.splice(element, 1)});
  dispatch(updateTodo(list));
};
```

Comment: I wouldn't suggest this approach. Since you're mutating the state directly

Comment: You are right, I fixed this.

Comment: Buddy, it's not about what's up to him, it's about what's right. You shouldn't mutate the state directly. You can use something which doesn't mutate state.

Comment: I know, you are right, I fixed it

Comment: And since you are talking about what is right, your answer doesn't point out the actual problem with his code

Comment: The problem is finding the index and filtering it. Added a few pieces of info for that. Hope that works

Comment: I ended up completing this with a version of your answer, instead of using setList and splicing the array, i just spliced the array in state, by doing `const element = list.todoItems.indexOf(id);
    list.todoItems.splice(element, 1);` I know this ultimately is not a great way at handling state, but filtering wasnt working for me, this works for now until i can implement a better solution

Answer (score 1):

Remove your indexOf logic and this will work.

You don't have to find the index of the array because you're already receiving it as a parameter.

```
const deleteItem = (id) => {
        setList({ todoItems: list.todoItems.filter((_, filterID) => filterID !== id) });
        console.log(list.todoItems);
        dispatch(updateTodo(list));
 };
```

Comment: and what do i do with element in this case? since you kept it in your filter, but never assign a value to it?

Comment: This should work